# Grace period ends in

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

В уведомлении о статусе конкурса отвалился перевод для периода щедрости.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Восстановил прежний перевод:

> Период отсрочки вознаграждения заканчивается $timeLeft$.

Ждите обновления базы и пересборки сайта.